how do i get rid of this run|debug button, and why is this button is inbetween my code
enter image description hereplease tell me how can i remove that run|debug button or why it showing in my code..
i just started learning java and i saw this button, i dont know why it is there.please help me remove this button.
and if possible please explain me about dubugging and this button.

IDEs will show more or less helpful links and buttons in your code. These are not really in your code; if you open the file in another editor, they will probably not be there (unless that other editor also likes to add them) --- try pasting your code in an email, for example, or open it in WordPad or vim. In this case your Visual Studio has seen that you have a main function, so it guesses you may actually want to run that function and offers the Run link. If you click that "Run", it will run your main function, as opposed you opening a terminal and typing something like java MyProgram.java.
Sometimes when you try to find a bug (a defect) in your code (i.e., it doesn't do what you expect it to do), running may not be good enough to find what's going wrong. Debugging however gives you the option to step through your code line by line, and inspect variables as you go. This makes it easier to understand what's happening. When you click "debug", it will run your code in debug mode.
I'd not worry about these Run and Debug links. But if you insist, there may be an option in the IDE to turn them off. But you also turn off easy access to these features.
